# Pyinstaller executable only works with virtual environment activated

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, pyinstaller, executable

I created a Python executable inside a virtual portable environment, created by Anaconda and the package conda-pack, with the following command on a terminal :

```
(venv) > pyinstaller --onefile --paths=src/ --exclude-module PyQt5 program.py
```

When I launch the built executable with the environment activated, the program works. **Without the environment actitaved, nothing happens**. After launching it, the executable stops (without any warnings or errors). The options --onefile and --exclude-module don't affect the results.

The modules of the virtual environment should be included inside the executable and then it shouldn't be needed to activate the environement. How to do so ?

Thanks.

Comment: first you could use `print()` in many places to see which part of code is executed and which can make problem. It is called `"print debuging"`. `Python` wasn't created to build executable and programs like `pyinstaller` may have problem to find all needed Python's modules and C/C++ libraries.

Comment: Yeah, I'd also guess it's a dynamic library issue. Even if it statically links direct dependencies, Conda is really heavy on building libraries with lots of dynamic linking  and often using relative paths. For Conda purposes, this is super useful for modularly reusing libraries across different environments, but can be challenging to resolve. Not sure your OS, but try using `ldd` (Linux) or `otool -L` (Mac) to see what libs the executable might be searching for.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct solution to your problem, but I was having the same issue and resolved it by using [py2exe](https://www.py2exe.org/) instead of pyinstaller.